# Getting the value of variables from event handlers in TKinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, events, handler

I wrote a simple neural network in Python. Now I'm implementing a graphical interface for configuring it.
The ComboBox widget contains the names of three types of activation functions: Sigmoid, Rely, Tanh. When the user selects one of them, the "changed" event handler displays a corresponding dialog message about the user's choice. The second handler "show_message" receives from the user the number of neurons in the hidden layer and also outputs it using a dialog message.

The main problem: how to get from the event handlers "changed" and "show_message" the parameters of the neural network set by the user (in this case, the type of activation function and the number of neurons in the hidden layer, that is, the contents of the variables "choice" and "choice2") for their further use in the main program?

Thank you in advance for your help. Source code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter.messagebox import showinfo
 
def raise_frame(frame):
    frame.tkraise()
    
def changed(event): 
     choice=combo.get()
     showinfo(title='Result', message=f'Type of activation function selected: {choice}')
        
def show_message():
    choice2=message.get()
    if choice2=="":
        showinfo("Result", "empty")
    else:
        showinfo("Result", message=f'Entered number of neurons: {message.get()}')
    raise_frame(f3)
    
root = Tk()
root.geometry("400x150")
 
f1 = Frame(root)
f2 = Frame(root)
f3 = Frame(root)
f4 = Frame(root)
 
for frame in (f1, f2, f3, f4):
    frame.grid(row=3, column=3, sticky='news')
    
factiv=("Sigmoid", "ReLU", "Tanh")
Label(f1, text='Select activation function').pack(side='top', padx=50, pady=10)
 
combo=ttk.Combobox(master=f1, state="readonly", values=factiv)
combo.current(0)
combo.pack(side='top', padx=50, pady=10)
combo.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", changed)
 
Button(f1, text='Next step', command=lambda: raise_frame(f2)).pack(side='top', padx=50, pady=10)
####################################################### end of first frame
 
message = StringVar()
Label(f2, text='Enter the number of neurons in the hidden layer:').pack(side='top', padx=50, pady=10)
message_entry = Entry(master=f2, textvariable=message)
message_entry.pack(side='top', padx=50, pady=10)
Button(f2, text='Next step', command=show_message).pack(side='top', padx=50, pady=10)
####################################################### end of the second frame, the third frame is still empty
 
raise_frame(f1)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Define them as global in functions or use an object-oriented programming.

Comment: Try this combo = StringVar() 
combo=ttk.Combobox(f1, textvariable=combo,state="readonly")
combo['values']= factiv
combo.current(0)

Comment: @Сергей Кох, I tried, but the error appears - NameError: name 'choice' is not defined

Comment: define them in the main program choice = None.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. You don't need iteration for frame. Because of the duplicate Just one root will do all the work. btw, I also add `combo = StringVar()`. Here is code.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter.messagebox import showinfo
 
def raise_frame(frame):
    frame.tkraise()
    
def changed(event): 
     choice=combo.get()
     showinfo(title='Result', message=f'Type of activation function selected: {choice}')
        
def show_message():
    choice2=message.get()
    if choice2=="":
        showinfo("Result", "empty")
    else:
        showinfo("Result", message=f'Entered number of neurons: {message.get()}')
    raise_frame(root)
    
root = Tk()
root.geometry("400x150")

    
factiv=("Sigmoid", "ReLU", "Tanh")
Label(root, text='Select activation function').pack(side='top', padx=50, pady=10)

combo = StringVar()   
combo=ttk.Combobox(root, textvariable=combo, state="readonly")
combo['values']= factiv
combo.current(0)
combo.pack(side='top', padx=50, pady=10)
combo.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", changed)
 
Button(root, text='Next step', command=lambda: raise_frame(root)).pack(side='top', padx=50, pady=10)
####################################################### end of first frame
 
message = StringVar()
Label(root, text='Enter the number of neurons in the hidden layer:').pack(side='top', padx=50, pady=10)
message_entry = Entry(root, textvariable=message)
message_entry.pack(side='top', padx=50, pady=10)
Button(root, text='Next step', command=show_message).pack(side='top', padx=50, pady=10)
####################################################### end of the second frame, the third frame is still empty
 
raise_frame(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: How can I get the value of the choice variable from the changed handler?

Comment: Use print(choice)

Comment: Error. Here is a screenshot. https://ibb.co/QNsRWgb

Comment: That page doesn't exist. paste  url in comment

Comment: What OS system are you running?

Comment: Windows 10. 
Uploaded the screenshot again - ibb.co/QNsRWgb

Comment: Not line 46. you put in line 10 ==> def changed(event): 
     choice=combo.get()
     print(choice)

Comment: But I need to get the value of this variable outside of the changed() handler. That is precisely the problem.

Comment: Did you get to see showinfo when pop up?

Comment: I just want to set up the ANN using the GUI and run it.

Comment: I haven't try ANN. I didn't know about it.

Comment: "Did you get to see showinfo when pop up?" - Yes, if you uncomment line 17. But I need the neural network settings in the main program.

Comment: How can I get the value of the choice variable outside the changed handler in the main program?

Comment: Oh ic what you meant. Used combo.get()  get outside of function.

Comment: I will be offline for now

Comment: This is what I tried to do too. But immediately a window opens with a message that the Sigmoid function is selected. Therefore, the program does not work correctly.

Comment: I tried to declare the choice variable as global in the changed handler, but an error appears - NameError: name 'choice' is not defined.